# How does iTunes determine whether an M4A file is "purchased"?

Tags: itunes, mp4, itunes-store, m4a

I'm trying to figure out how iTunes determines whether an M4A file is a "purchased" (as in "Purchased AAC audio file"). I tried removing the iTunes Account Type tag from the file using [MP4v2](https://code.google.com/p/mp4v2/), but the tag won't go away! I'm thinking there must be some special bits set in the file somewhere.

Comment: I know little about iTunes, but I'm guessing it matches the track against your own library.  Apple would keep a record of which tracks you have purchased, and if that track is within that set iTunes sees it as "playable"/"purchased".  Don't know what it would do without an internet connection though.  Perhaps it does mark it somehow for that case.

Like I said though, I'm not an iTunes user and know very little about it.

Comment: @celestialorb Nah I don't think there's any matching going on. Songs purchased by other iTunes accounts still show as "purchased". Thanks for trying though. =)